# Which algorithm would be the faster algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

As per Big O notations, if time complexity of one algorithm is O(2^n) and the other is O(n^1000), then which would be faster one?

Comment: Big O doesn't tell you the speed, it tells you how quickly the number of operations grows. Unless n is near infinite (which you'll never hit on a computer) you can't actually say which will be "faster" in terms of actual execution speed.

Answer (score 4):

How to recognize overall behavior for some non-obvious cases: get logarithm of both functions.
*(Sometimes we can also get ratio of the functions and evaluate ratio limit for large n's, here this approach is not good)*

```
log(2^n) = n*log(2)
log(n^1000) = 1000*log(n)
```

The first result is slanted line with positive coefficient. The second one's plot is convex curve with negative second derivative, so the first function becomes larger at some big n value.

[How plot looks](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20n*ln%282%29%2C%201000*ln%28n%29%2C%20n%3D1..20000)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

O(n^1000) is in the same class as (n^2) and O(n^777777777) which is Polynomial time, whereas O(2^n) is Exponential time which is way slower than Polynomial

https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: Under a limit definition of *slow*